# Setting a MutableLiveData within coroutine Main dispatcher returns InvocationTargetException | SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I pursue [this coroutine use cases](https://github.com/LukasLechnerDev/Kotlin-Coroutine-Use-Cases-on-Android). In **usecase10**; a factorial of a number is calculated in a coroutine background thread (Default dispatcher), and then converted to a String to be displayed on the UI via a `MutableLiveData` object.

**Simplified ViewModel:**

```
class CalculationInBackgroundViewModel(
    private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
)() {

    fun uiState(): LiveData<T> = uiState
    val uiState: MutableLiveData<T> = MutableLiveData()


    fun performCalculation(factorialOf: Int) {
        uiState.value = UiState.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

                var result: BigInteger = BigInteger.ZERO
                val computationDuration = measureTimeMillis {
                    result = calculateFactorialOf(factorialOf)
                }

                var resultString = ""
                val stringConversionDuration = measureTimeMillis {
                    resultString = convertToString(result)
                }

                uiState.value = 
                    UiState.Success(
                        resultString,
                        computationDuration,
                        stringConversionDuration
                    ) // <<<<< The exception raised here


            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                UiState.Error("Error while calculating result")
            }
        }
    }

    // factorial of n (n!) = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ... * n
    private suspend fun calculateFactorialOf(number: Int): BigInteger =
        withContext(defaultDispatcher) {
            var factorial = BigInteger.ONE
            for (i in 1..number) {
                factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i.toLong()))
            }
            factorial
        }

    private suspend fun convertToString(number: BigInteger): String =
        withContext(defaultDispatcher) {
            number.toString()
        }
}
```

The following exception occurs exactly on `setValue()` on the `MutableLiveData`:

```
2021-12-27 22:45:12.484 21582-21582/? E/A: Exception while registering uid importance
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerUidObserver from pid=21582, uid=10032 requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerUidObserver(IActivityManager.java:9032)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.addOnUidImportanceListener(ActivityManager.java:3641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2021-12-27 22:52:39.450 22273-22273/? E/A: Exception while registering uid importance
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerUidObserver from pid=22273, uid=10032 requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerUidObserver(IActivityManager.java:9032)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.addOnUidImportanceListener(ActivityManager.java:3641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2021-12-27 22:55:23.110 1641-1641/? E/BackupTransportManager: Couldn't get transport name.
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:764)
        at com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub$Proxy.name(IBackupTransport.java:369)
        at com.android.server.backup.TransportManager$TransportConnection.onServiceConnected(TransportManager.java:339)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1652)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1681)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:416)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:267)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:787)
2021-12-27 22:55:23.147 1641-1641/? E/BackupTransportManager: Couldn't get transport name.
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:764)
        at com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub$Proxy.name(IBackupTransport.java:369)
        at com.android.server.backup.TransportManager$TransportConnection.onServiceConnected(TransportManager.java:339)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1652)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1681)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:416)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:267)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:787)
2021-12-27 22:56:07.007 23444-23444/? E/A: Exception while registering uid importance
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerUidObserver from pid=23444, uid=10032 requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerUidObserver(IActivityManager.java:9032)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.addOnUidImportanceListener(ActivityManager.java:3641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2021-12-27 22:57:21.695 24065-24065/? E/A: Exception while registering uid importance
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerUidObserver from pid=24065, uid=10032 requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerUidObserver(IActivityManager.java:9032)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.addOnUidImportanceListener(ActivityManager.java:3641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.e.a.a.run(PG:9) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.b(PG:1) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.by.run(PG:1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The expcetion is resolved by using `postValue()` instead of `setValue()`; but why shouldn't `setValue` safe here? it's already running within the Main dispatcher that is inherited by `viewModelScope`?

Comment: Could it be something happening on the observer side? The error seems to have to do with registering an observer.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The observer callback didn't get triggered unfortunately, [here it is in the activity](https://github.com/LukasLechnerDev/Kotlin-Coroutine-Use-Cases-on-Android/blob/coroutines_course_complete/app/src/main/java/com/lukaslechner/coroutineusecasesonandroid/usecases/coroutines/usecase10/CalculationInBackgroundActivity.kt#L25)

Comment: There is an interesting thing, it just got run on API 30; the exception raised on API 27

Answer (score 1):

No, this error is something else. It has to do with `IActivityManager`, it could be triggered when you execute `setValue` but the exception is happening in one of the observers.

You will have more info once you find who that observer is and what is it doing.

Comment: Most likely it's related to the observer, [here it is](https://github.com/LukasLechnerDev/Kotlin-Coroutine-Use-Cases-on-Android/blob/coroutines_course_complete/app/src/main/java/com/lukaslechner/coroutineusecasesonandroid/usecases/coroutines/usecase10/CalculationInBackgroundActivity.kt#L25).. Its callback didn't get triggered; something internally raises this exception.. Any ideas how can this be avoided?

Comment: @Zain, don't guess. Comment out this code and see if it solves your problem. Once you know for sure what causes this exception, ask a new question about it.